# Unable to process XML. Getting The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xml-parsing, java-7

Can you please check what is wrong with this XML. Client is sending this XML request to process my application.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:eze="http://ezeepay_test">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <eze:RequestService
 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <InputXml xsi:type="xsd:string">
                <?xml version="1.0"
 encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <Request>
                    <BankID>05</BankID>
                    <TransactionID>1004114741235</TransactionID>
                    <TransactionType>Payment</TransactionType>
                    <ServiceType>Bill</ServiceType>
                    <TransactionDateStamp>04-04-2019 11:43:13</TransactionDateStamp>
                    <Amount>500</Amount>
                    <PaymentType>Cash</PaymentType>
                </Request>
            </InputXml>
        </eze:RequestService>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to use xPath to iterate through the nodes to read the elements. But when I am parsing this XML I am getting the following Error.

I am prasing it using DocumentBuilderFactory.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

//This is where I am getting Error.
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XMLRequestString)));
```

Please let me know what manipulation I can do at my code Level.

Comment: The problem is the XML you are parsing.  It is *fundamentally* broken.  It is not legal to embed a Processing Instruction (PI) with the name "xml" in a document.  That can only appear in the Prolog of an XML document; i.e. at the beginning; see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-prolog

Comment: There is no proper "manipulation" that you can do at your code level to fix this.  The problem must be fixed by correcting whatever is generating this **invalid** XML.

Comment: I do not have access to manipulate the invalid XML at client code. Since Client is requesting our application using this XML, we need to modify the code at our side. Right now I am searching for <?xml tag and taking the substring till </Request> tag. So that I can process the request correctly.

Comment: You have a defined interface with your client, representing a contract, and you have wisely decided to define this interface using international standards such as SOAP and XML. If you switch to using a proprietary variant of these standards then you will end up increasing costs for both sides of the interface, because you can no longer use off-the-shelf tooling. Using standards saves money! Don't allow the other party to the contract to drift away from the specification, however tempting it seems; you are throwing money away.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is that the data that has been sent is not compliant with the SOAP and XML standards and your server is quite right to reject it. The specific rule it is breaking is that the construct `<?xml....?>` can only appear at the start of the document (it would be an XML declaration if it appeared at the start; it would be a processing instruction if it were not named "xml"; as it is, it is neither).

Don't be tempted to change your server code to accept any garbage the client sends you: that is the road to ruin.

Comment: I agree with you. This is what even I have tried initially. Actually we have our production environment which is consuming this request. In my case, I am working on creating a service simulation environment where I have to use this XML only. I have tried my best to convince the client that do not work using malformatted XML. Since it is business requirement, they are not willing to change anything in their code as it is working in production environment. I hope you will understand my situation.

Comment: Read carefully the details of your contract with the customer.  If the contract specifies requirements and the requirements state that the API is implemented as SOAP / XML, then **your customer** is in breach of the contract.  This is not valid SOAP / XML.  What they are asking for is a **variation** of the contract, and you are entitled to charge them extra to implement that variation.

Comment: Yes. We understand your situation.  But I (at least) think you are not managing your customer relations properly.

Comment: Yes, I do understand your problem. I have worked for companies that did disastrous things to their products because they thought the customer was always right. The experience has taught me to resist such demands.